# Css file doesn't open after suddenly pc shutdown - Visual Studio 2015

Tags: css, asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

While working on the project, my computer suddenly shut down. After I turned it on and opened my project with vs, I saw the project CSS file does not open and the following message is displayed:

[image]

Then I tried to open the CSS file with notepad but the empty file was displayed.!!!

I reset the Visual Studio settings but the problem still exists.!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I'm not 100% on this, I believe your CSS file is Corrupted. The sudden shutdown might have damaged the CSS file you had in VS.

If you have version copies of this project, just fall back to one that works.

If you don't have copies, I suggest you start, just to minimise the damage in the future. The only thing you can do now is to, delete the file and create a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Check for the TMP file it seems that vs through windows policy saves a temp before attempting the copy. You can view that file in the editor and copy paste it's contens into a file with the same name as your css file.